# Знак в предложении на "Где бы ни..."

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой (если вообще какой-нибудь) знак должен стоять в предложении по модели: "Где бы ни был он (-) всегда получал своё".

Или так: "Как бы они ни старались (-) (всё равно (,)) бричка не ехала".

Благодарю!

Comment: Arsenii, это точно такие же предложения, как в предыдущем вопросе ("Что бы он ни делал..."). Можно ставить или запятую, или тире. // "Как бы они н**и** старались..." // После "всё равно" запятая не нужна.

Comment: Понял! Спасибо!